# How can I handle the file download from Loopback storage? Redirect the file request

Tags: node.js, express, backend, loopbackjs

Here is what I want to do:
When user's browser is trying to download any file (image or else) I want to handle it and check if file exists in local file system. If the file doesn't exist I want to pass the browser the file from another source (AWS S3 for example). How can I do this?

I've tried to use Loopback's beforeRemote hook:

```
Container.beforeRemote('download', (ctx, modelInstance, next) => {
  console.log(ctx.req);
  next();
});
```

I've got request parameter but I can't figure out what I can do with it. Maybe I should some kind of middleware, but I don't know how.